Maximum Count of Subarray having sum >= k and length >l
For a given array we need to find the maximum number of subarrays possible. Conditions:
1.The sum of each subarray should be >= minSum
2.The length of the subarray should be >= minLen
We need to find the maximum number of subarray possible in the given array.
Ex: n=6 array= [5, 7, 9, 12, 10, 13] minLen = 2 minSum = 15
Output: 2
Explanation:
Since the min length of the sub-array should be > 2 && sum should be >minSum so the two subarray will be as 7+9+12=28 and 10+13 =23
I tried but I have failed multiple times, so seeking help here.

And WHAT have you tried? SO is not a codefactoy where you drop in your requirements and get out ready to use code

What about 7+9 or 9+12 or 12+10? Do the subarrays have to be distinct?  Your reuqirements are far to unclear to give a meaningful answer
